# Add a shortcut in ribon of task list

Tags: sharepoint-server, sandbox-solution, tasks

I've a task list and in the ribbon under Items I've a blue buton "Assign to me"

Do you know how I can add this to my other lists? And how is it working?

[image]

Comment: this is your custom solution, no OOTB functionality avaiable. i think you should enable that feature on all lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come with the solution.

In sharepoint designer, on the task list, in the bottom right you have custom actions.
With this, you can add an action in the ribbon of the list

Answer (score 0):

This is not OOTB functionality, it is a Custom Action provisioned by a third-party solution (`.wsp`)

With a little luck, they have a feature that you can enable per web / site to add this to all Task lists in that web /site.

If not, you would have to ask the developers to change their functionality, o[r you can write some similar functionality yourself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh500259(v=office.14).aspx).

It could also, as you said yourself, have been added by using [SharePoint Designer](http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.be/2010/06/sharepoint-2010-add-button-to-ribbon.html), in that case you would have to try to mimic the behavior that way (using designer, and workflows)

Comment: it couldn't be a custom action like view ribon in sharepoint designer? http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.be/2010/06/sharepoint-2010-add-button-to-ribbon.html

Comment: Good add! Surely it can (if it only is meant to exist in one place)

Answer (score 0):

Just an fyi for anyone that is stumped on adding custom actions on task lists --

I've found for task lists, specifically, if you are creating a new View Ribbon custom action, you will need to change the Ribbon Location syntax to: Ribbon.**Tasks**.Actions.Controls._children instead of Ribbon.**ListItem**.Actions.Controls._children for all other list types.